# core:forEach in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, foreach

I have this code to display details from database to jsp. I'm using core:forEach to sort through the list of results.But now inorder to simplify jsp code I'm implementing the core:forEach in javascript.And I'm displaying the results in a dynamically created table. But now while using core:forEach in javascript, only the last value in the list is getting displayed. Code is as follows.

```
window.onload = function CreateTable()
{
    <core:forEach items="${requestScope.projectWiseDetails}" var="row">;  //first list sorting based on project name
      var tablecontents = "";
      tablecontents = "<table>";             //dynamic table
      tablecontents += "<tr>";
      tablecontents += "<td>" + "Resource Name" + "</td>";
      tablecontents += "</tr>";
        <core:forEach items="${row.onsite3to5YearsList}" var="resource">     //second sorting which comes under project name
          tablecontents += "<tr>";
          tablecontents += "<td>" +<core:out value="${resource.resourceName}"></core:out>+ "</td>";
        </core:forEach> 
     tablecontents += "</tr>";
     tablecontents += "</table>";
  </core:forEach>
  document.getElementById("tablespace").innerHTML = tablecontents;     //attaching the table to an element


}


 <p id="tablespace"></p>  //This is where the table gets generated
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overriding `tablecontents` everytime, take `var tablecontents = ""` outside the loop, then replace `tablecontents = "<table>"` with `tablecontents += "<table>"`.

```
window.onload = function CreateTable()
{

    var tablecontents = "";
    <core:forEach items="${requestScope.projectWiseDetails}" var="row">;  //first list 
    tablecontents += "<table>";
    // The rest of your code
```